# Applying XSLT to XML on ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, xslt

I am following the tutorial here: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/XML/Applying-XSLT-to-XML-Using-ASP.NET/2/

The tutorial shows how one converts xml to html via xslt.  Unfortunately, one of the first steps is to "Drag an XML control from toolbox on to the webform".  Which section of tools is this and which control are they talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the standard section of the toolbox.

You can create it via source view as well:

```
<asp:Xml ID="xmlMyXmlControl" runat="server" DocumentSource="myXml.xml" TransformSource="myXsl.xsl"></asp:Xml>
```

Additional information on this control can be found at the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Xml" in the "Standard" menu in Visual Studio.